# simple angularjs function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Just trying to change the background color based on the what the user clicks

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:{{bc}};overflow-x:hidden;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0;">
```

AND

```
<div style="width:100%;height:20%;border:2px solid black;" ng-click="sports(FFE648);">
    <img src="logo-01.svg" style="border:2px solid black;min-width:60px;min-height:60px;width:100%;height:55%;"/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.sports=function(colorpick){
        $scope.animation="animated4 bounceOutRightCustom";
        $scope.animationleft="animated4 bounceOutLeftCustom";
        $scope.bc=colorpick;
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.animation="";
          $scope.animationleft="";
            }, 4100);
    }

});
</script>
```

I don't know what is wrong...should be pretty simple solution :(

Comment: `ng-click="sports('#FFE648');">`

Answer (score 2):

Your `ng-click` expression is invalid. You need color to be a string.

```
ng-click="sports('#FFE648');">
```

Also I recommend you to take a look at [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive.